# Async await Task.WhenAll(tasks); stuck, won't continue with code

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

It's 7am and not the good kind. I'm tired, I have spaghetti code, I just want an explanation. First time working with `async` in general. This is the code:

```
namespace TargetFinder
{
    public class AsyncRandomIP
    {
        private const string BaseFolderName = "TargetLocatorData/AsyncRandomIP";
        private const string FoundIPsFileName = "found_ips.txt";
        private const string UnreachableIPsFileName = "unreachable_ips.txt";

        public static async Task ScanAsync(Config config, int port, int amount,
            Form1 form, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string baseFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), BaseFolderName);
            Methods.EnsureDirectoryExists(baseFolderPath);

            var random = new Random();
            var unreachableIPs = Methods.LoadIPsFromFile(UnreachableIPsFileName,
                baseFolderPath);
            var foundIPs = Methods.LoadIPsFromFile(FoundIPsFileName, baseFolderPath);

            var ipQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (config.AllowRepeatScans)
                {
                    ipQueue.Add(Methods.GenerateRandomIPAddress(random));
                }
                else
                {
                    string ipAddress;

                    do
                    {
                        ipAddress = Methods.GenerateRandomIPAddress(random);
                    } while (unreachableIPs.Contains(ipAddress));
                    ipQueue.Add(ipAddress);
                    form.UpdateConsole("NewQueueSet: " + ipQueue);
                }
            }

            int concurrentThreads = config.ConcurrentThreads;
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < concurrentThreads; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    foreach (string ipAddress in ipQueue
                        .GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
                    {
                        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        await ProcessIPAsync(config, port, unreachableIPs,
                            foundIPs, baseFolderPath, form, ipAddress);
                    }
                }));
            }
            form.UpdateConsole(Environment.NewLine + "Waiting for finish:");
            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                form.UpdateConsole(
                    Environment.NewLine + "IPs with requested service:");
                foreach (string ip in foundIPs)
                {
                    form.UpdateConsole(Environment.NewLine + ip);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task ProcessIPAsync(Config config, int port,
            HashSet<string> unreachableIPs, HashSet<string> foundIPs,
            string baseFolderPath, Form1 form, string ipAddress)
        {
            if (Methods.IsIPReachable(ipAddress))
            {
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.SendTimeout = config.ClientSendTimeoutMilliseconds;
                        await client.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, port);

                        form.UpdateConsole(Environment.NewLine + $"IP: {ipAddress},
                            Service found: true");

                        foundIPs.Add(ipAddress);
                        Methods.SaveIPsToFile(foundIPs, FoundIPsFileName,
                            baseFolderPath);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        form.UpdateConsole(Environment.NewLine + $"IP: {ipAddress},
                            Service found: false");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                        foundIPs.Add(ipAddress);
                        Methods.SaveIPsToFile(foundIPs, FoundIPsFileName,
                            baseFolderPath);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                form.UpdateConsole(
                    Environment.NewLine + $"IP: {ipAddress}, Not reachable");
                unreachableIPs.Add(ipAddress);
                Methods.SaveIPsToFile(unreachableIPs, UnreachableIPsFileName,
                    baseFolderPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out where the tasks are freezing and not completing, the console isn't much of use, neither is ChatGPT. If someone could check it out and let me know, open to criticism about the way I wrote this, not my proudest project. If someone could help out id be grateful.

Additional form1 code.

```
namespace TargetFinder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SynchronizationContext uiContext;
        private CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thread_tb.Text = Convert.ToString(thread_trackbar.Value);
            if (print_res_bt.Checked)
            {
                format_bt.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                format_bt.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thread_tb.Text = "4";
            thread_trackbar.Value = 4;
            amount_tb.Text = "50";
            timeout_tb.Text = "3000";
            print_res_bt.Checked = true;
            format_bt.SelectedItem = ".TXT";

        }

        private void configurationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void print_res_bt_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void directoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            directory_set.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void scan_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int port = Convert.ToInt32(port_tb.Text);
                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(amount_tb.Text);

                cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); // Reset CancellationTokenSource

                Info.Main(port, amount, this, cancelTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Scan cancelled.");
            }
        }
        public void UpdateConsole(string text)
        {
            uiContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate
            {
                console.AppendText(text);
            }), null);
        }

        private void cancel_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            console.Text = "";
        }

        private void set_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int clientSendTimeoutMilliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(timeout_tb.Text);
            int concurrentThreads = Convert.ToInt32(thread_tb.Text);
            bool allowRepeatScans = repeat_scan_bt.Checked;
            ConfigManager.SetConfig(clientSendTimeoutMilliseconds, concurrentThreads, allowRepeatScans);
            MessageBox.Show("Configuration updated.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `neither is chatgpt` why did you expect statistically generated text to be of any help?

Comment: `WhenAll` doesn't freeze, it completes only if all tasks complete. When you use `GetConsumingEnumerable`, the enumeration won't complete until the *publisher* completes it with `CompleteAdding`. Asynchronous code *doesn't* have to be spaghetti code. Separate publishers and subscribers into separate classes and use the appropriate classes. The asynchronous pub/sub collection is Channel<T>, not `BlockingCollection`. Tasks aren't threads, they're promises. `Parallel.ForEachAsync` eliminates a lot of the code in the question by taking care of creating workers and passing items to them

Comment: That is indeed spaghetti code. It also looks like you're passing a Windows Form object into a method that is doing a bunch of async work. I highly recommend separating this code ( `ScanAsync` ) from the UI bits. Handling scheduler coordination is a non trivial task.

Comment: I don't see `ipQueue.CompleteAdding();` call anywhere. Also I'm not sure that it is needed here at all, something like `Parallel.ForEachAsync` should do just fine.

Comment: The way the code is written there's no reason to use `BlockingQueue` at all. Use a normal List or Queue, then use `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(list,async (item,ct)=>await someMethod(item,ct))` to process the results using multiple tasks. By default, as many items as there are cores are processed concurrently. You can change that through the options parameter

Comment: Probably OP wanted to handle one ipaddress at at time, and i don't think creating a number of TcpClients concurrentlly would be a great idea.

Comment: `concurrentThreads` times of `ipQueue` enumeration is a nonsense. Full refactoring required.

Comment: Ryan, you are right i wanted to process 1 ip address at a time. However creating concurrently multiple(4 in my case) of tcp clients shouldn't be a bad idea? Because of speed, if only one is being checked at a time and you have to wait for one to finish for the next to start, if you're scanning 100 ips it takes a lot of time, this way its done in second, instead of minutes. Tested it myself.

Comment: What is the type of the application? WinForms?

Comment: Are you running this program with the VS debugger attached, or standalone in release mode?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it is WinForms, this part of the code is placed in a separate class. Away from the Form. The VS debugger is attached and no issues are being displayed, i implemented new code from Panagiotis Kanavos using the Parallel method. Now it is better and i found out that when i ping only 1 ip, everything works fine, but as soon as there is 2 ips being pinged, any code after the wait all tasks doesn't get executed and my memory doesn't jump down after the scan is finished which is also a new issue Im experiencing. Im not very skilled so sorry if im just dumb :/

Comment: Please search your project for `.Wait()`, `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. If any of those exists, [you have a problem](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html "Don't block on async code").

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i searched my whole project for them, not a single one. I cant figure out the issue at all. Any ideas on what my next steps could be?

Comment: Please include in the question the `form.UpdateConsole` method. In WinForms applications you must be very careful to not allow any interaction with UI controls from any other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: As a side-note, abstracting your code and organizing it in compartments (`TargetFinder.AsyncRandomIP` etc) might not be a good idea before having a firm grasp on the technologies involved. Keeping all the code in a single file (`Form.cs`), and keeping it as minimal as possible, might serve you better at debugging your program, and getting help from the community.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thank you for the suggestion will keep that in mind. I added the form code.

Comment: I reviewed the code that you posted ([revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76885024/4)). AFAICS there is nothing problematic with this code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thank you, I must say I dont feel as dumb anymore. Ill just rewrite the whole code start fresh, might see something i missed, thank you so much for trying.

Comment: In case you end up with a new minimal implementation that reproduces the same issue, you could consider posting a new question about it.